# How can I have RedactorRails method passing authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redactor

I use redactor rails gem.

When I try to upload picture, I see:

```
Started POST "/redactor_rails/pictures?authenticity_token=g1JQetiggTDMwYoG2CnVz5ilnBoXReONW9iwgt5%2FJy4%3D" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-31 22:02:10 +0400
Processing by RedactorRails::PicturesController#create as HTML
#other logs

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:controller=>"info", :action=>"app_index"}):
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:55:in `authorize'
```

What actually points that this doesn't pass my custom authorization:

```
  def authorize
     @current_permission = current_permission
     if @current_permission.allow?(params[:controller], params[:action])
        return true
      else
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end
```

Current permission is made like this:

```
   allow :controller, [:m1, m2, ....]
   allow :users, [:new,:create,:uniqueness, :show, :create_guest, :edit_user_by_reset, :update_pass, :email_confirmation]
   # so on
```

What have I tried:

```
   allow "RedactorRails::PicturesController", [:create]
   allow  :pictures, [:create]
   allow :redactor_rails, [:create]
```

None of that works.

Any ideas?

Comment: Though it doesn't address your problem *(I'd like to see your `allow?` and `current_permission` methods)*, I like to point out the **[pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit)** gem when I see fragile custom authorization like this.

Comment: @Deefour, you are wrong, it is based on RailsCasts tutorual and works like cancan on 100%, just custom

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm wrong about, as I was merely suggesting a well tested, popular, **light weight** alternative to your current authorization. If you took offense to me referring to it as 'fragile', I apologize, but it so for appears to be the source of the issue you're here seeking help for.

Comment: @Deefour, of course **authorization** forbides something unmentioned in white list, that is how white-list authorization works (white-list considered much more better option). And actually, any gem (white-list approach) anyway will ask me which controllers and methods have permission, and I will face this problem again. I need to know what controller name will respond to query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   allow :"redactor_rails/pictures", [:index, :create]
   allow :"redactor_rails/documents", [:index, :create]
```

So, the main useful information - that's how you declare controller method somewhere to match redactor